# check_hostname requires server_hostname

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy

I was using this code with Python 3.9 and worked fine but I have updated to an alpha version of Python 3.10 and now I get this exception:

```
proxy = {
    "http": "http://" + proxy_ip,
    "https": "https://" + proxy_ip
}

requests.get("https://www.url.org/", proxies=proxy, timeout=10)
```

Error:

```
check_hostname requires server_hostname
```

I change the code to this as mentioned in another question but I got another error

```
proxy = {
    "http": proxy_ip,
    "https": proxy_ip
}

requests.get("https://www.url.org/", proxies=proxy, timeout=10)
```

Error:

```
Proxy URL had no scheme, should start with http:// or https://
```

Any ideas besides downgrading the Python version?

All Code:

```
import requests
from os import getcwd
from tqdm import tqdm

# Check proxy
def checkProxy(proxy_ip):
    proxy = {
        "http": proxy_ip,
        "https": proxy_ip
    }

    try:
        requests.get("https://www.url.org/", proxies=proxy, timeout=10)

        return True
    except:
        return False


# Main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('proxy.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        proxies = f.readlines()

    proxies = [x.strip() for x in proxies]

    f = open("proxy-valid.txt",'a+')

    for proxy in tqdm(proxies):
        if checkProxy(proxy):
            f.write(proxy + "\n")
            f.flush()

    f.close()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\NG\utils\proxy-checker.py", line 39, in <module>
    if checkProxy(proxy):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\NG\utils\proxy-checker.py", line 12, in checkProxy
    requests.get("https://www.url.org/", proxies=proxy, timeout=10)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 414, in send
    raise InvalidURL(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Proxy URL had no scheme, should start with http:// or https://
```

Thanks

Comment: You probably have a function called `check_hostname`, could you post the code of that function too?

Comment: Please add the full traceback to your question!

Comment: well you posted the second variant where you obviously dont have `http` or `https` in  url, you need to change it back to `"https://" + proxy_ip `

Comment: and then show us `check_hostname` function

Comment: I don't have that function @BijayRegmi

Comment: What version of urllib are you using, and does your proxy server have a specific port?

Comment: 1.26.4. I have tried with multiple ports same problem @BijayRegmi